# jquery - how to extract contents from a page which shows xml data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have a link

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/

when i directly open it in a browser it is showing xml output.

can any one help me how to get all `"Contents"` tag elements' data from that xml using jquery ajax.

below is my code which i have tried but it is not working for me

```
 <html>
<head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#dvContent").append("<ul></ul>");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml){ 
                $(xml).find('Contents').each(function(){
                var key = $(this).find('Key').text();
                var lastmod = $(this).find('LastModified').text();
                $("<li></li>").html(key + ", " + lastmod).appendTo("#dvContent ul");
            });
            },
            error: function() {
            alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
            }
        });
    });    
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
  font-family  : Arial;
  font-size  : 10pt;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="dvContent">
    dfsdfs
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can parse your xml returned from remote script using `jQuery.parseXML()`. ref:http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/

Answer (score 0):

Cross-domain ajax is not possible . [Refer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: so is there any way to get the contents of that xml

Comment: Maybe you could get contents of file by server side script, and then manipulate it...

Answer (score 0):

Good working example for this problem is [here](http://www.isgoodstuff.com/2012/07/22/cross-domain-xml-using-jquery/)